# Performance and styles problem after changing permalink structure

Tags: permalinks, performance, css

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Performance and styles not working fine after changing permalink structure](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/81953/performance-and-styles-not-working-fine-after-changing-permalink-structure)

Fist I was using default option of permalink and everything was fine (speed is ok, my own created theme is working fine) but now I change default structure to post name structure of permalink now I am not getting 404 error but the problems are :

1 - Whole website is loading very slow (pages,post) .

2 - My custom theme is not working fine means styles are not working on single page or single            post.

I checked my .htaccess file where the code is :

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /wordpress_1/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /wordpress_1/index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

**Note** : wordpress_1 is directory name.

Comment: Figuring out why your site loads slow will require intimate knowledge of your server and your roll-your-own theme. You have not provided enough information.

Comment: I am working on localhost

Comment: Yes, I know that. It does not change the fact that you have not provided enough information. I don't even know how to start guessing at the solution. It is probably a combination of things, but it is hard to tell since all you provided was the content of your `.htaccess` file and that isn't likely relevant since you don't have a 404s.

Comment: @s_ha_dum then tell me what more to tell you. I have provided you what is written in .htaccsess file and I am using my own css instead of default wordpress theme twntytwelve.

Comment: Disable all plugins and switch to TwentyEleven. Does it still happen?

Comment: @toscho I did and styles are loading fine when using TwentyEleven