# Performance and styles not working fine after changing permalink structure

Tags: permalinks, performance, css

Fist I was using default option of permalink and everything was fine (speed is ok, my own created theme is working fine) but now I change default structure to post name structure of permalink now I am not getting 404 error but the problems are :

1 - Whole website is loading very slow (pages,post) .

2 - My custom theme is not working fine means styles are not working on single page or single post.

I checked my .htaccess file where the code is :

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /wordpress_1/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /wordpress_1/index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

**Note** : wordpress_1 is directory name.

Answer (score 0):

Your `.htaccess` should not be modified on the WordPress part, so it should always be:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

It looks like if you have your WordPress install in a Subdirectory of the folder you map your domain to. In this case, you will have to do the following:

Copy your WordPress `index.php` into the root directory, and change the path of `require('./wp-blog-header.php');` to use your directory instead. Should be like this:

```
<?php
/**
 * Front to the WordPress application. This file doesn't do anything, but loads
 * wp-blog-header.php which does and tells WordPress to load the theme.
 *
 * @package WordPress
 */

/**
 * Tells WordPress to load the WordPress theme and output it.
 *
 * @var bool
 */
define('WP_USE_THEMES', true);

/** Loads the WordPress Environment and Template */
require('./wordpress_1/wp-blog-header.php');
```

You may also need to copy your `.htaccess` into this directory.

In your WordPress Settings you have to change the option `WordPress URL` to `http://yourdomain.com/wordpress_1` while leaving the option `Siteurl` at `http://yourdomain.com/`.

This should do the trick for your Styles and Performance!

Comment: I have htdcos/wordpress_1/index.php

Comment: Yeah, as I expected, so this solution should work for you.

Comment: Sorry! I think speed is now ok but when I click on any post it take me to localhost/xampp

Comment: Can you post a Link to that?

Comment: I can not put my Link here because it is on localhost of company's computer. It's a protocol.

Comment: What is n the index.php of your root?

Comment: Pardon! Please I am not getting what do you mean?

Comment: When I used your above code require('./wordpress_1/wp-blog-header.php'); then it is showing following error Warning: require(.wordpress_1/wp-blog-header.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\wordpress_1\index.php on line 17

Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required '.wordpress_1/wp-blog-header.php' (include_path='.;C:\xampp\php\PEAR;C:\xampp\php\Zend\library\;C:\xampp\php\PEAR\PHPUnit') in C:\xampp\htdocs\wordpress_1\index.php on line 17